# Search user not working Solr

Tags: search, indexing, solr

User's are indexed with lastname,firstname. When I am trying to search with a space in middle does not return the required result. This happens because space is considered as separate word. How do we handle this situation?

Example:

lastname,firstname - returns user

lastname, firstname - return fails

firstname lastname - return fails

Comment: This depends on how your field type is defined. What is the field type of the field you're searching, and how is that field type defined?

Comment: You could filter whitespaces in your field types. Would that help?